# $B=\{x \in A: d(x,\partial A)\geq \varepsilon\}$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $A$ be a compact and connected subset of $\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I would like to know if there exists a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B=\{x \in A: d(x,\partial A)\geq \varepsilon\}$ is also a connected subset of $\Omega$ that is not empty.

I was trying to write set $B$ as the image of a continuous application by a connected set. I could not see a counterexample to this affirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If any $\epsilon$ is ok, then take $\epsilon$ to be large enough so that your subset is $A$ (it exists because $A$ is compact) so $B$ is $A$ and thus connected. If you want to know if this is true for a certain sequence of epsilon of limit $0$, then $[0;1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ will give you a counterexample (it won't work for $\epsilon < \dfrac{1}{2}$).

Comment: I do not know if there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B$ is connected. I imagine that using the compactness of the set A it is possible to guarantee the existence of this $\varepsilon>0$, since (intuitively) $B$ is a "copy" of $ A $. I also want $B \subsetneq A$.

Comment: The example you cited is not a counterexample because I could take $\varepsilon=1/3$.

Comment: Sorry, I did mistake on the inequality. But there is still a real so that it works: if it's big enough, then the set will be empty.

Comment: I want a small $\varepsilon>0$ in order to have $\emptyset \neq B \subsetneq A \subset \Omega $.

Comment: Take two disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$ one centered at the point $(-1,0)$ and the other $(1,0)$ with both a radius of $0.5$, and had $[-1;1] \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ to that. We call this set $A$. The set $B$ (with your notation) is either empty or not connected.

Comment: A slightly simpler version of the example in @Paul's last comment: Let $A$ be the union of two closed disks that are tangent to each other.  Then $B$ will be disconnected for all positive values of $\varepsilon$ (under the convention that the empty set is not connected).